# Do different ngrams share embedding in Fasttext?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, word-embedding, text-classification, pretrained-models

As per Section 3.2 in the [original paper on Fasttext](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.04606.pdf), the authors state:

> In order to bound the memory requirements of our model, we use a
> hashing function that maps n-grams to integers in 1 to K

Does this mean the model computes only K embeddings regardless of the number of distinct ngrams extracted from the training corpus, and if 2 different ngrams collide when hashed, they share the same embedding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

This trick reflects that there are many possible character n-grams, but only relatively few of them contribute to the word's meaning. Instead of resolving what n-grams are the most salient ones, they just opt for a stochastic solution.